# Automatically input gtin number in products

Tags: magento-1.9, products, google-shopping

I have over 50,000 products in Magento version 1.9.1.0 and I want to list them on google shopping.

My question is, are there any Magento extensions that will automatically generate [GTIN](http://www.gtin.info/) numbers for all the 50,000 products I have?

Comment: I have a store for testing the SOAP API. I want to set and fetch GTIN. How can we do that? P.S. I am not the magento developer and I consume the API via SOAP

Answer (score 0):

u can create or get list or csv file for all those products and u can create array or object .
by creating external data script, within that script u have to load all customer and by id of that customer u can check for GTIN no. to that product and update field in Database with that script.

just for reference 
https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/6324461?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=6324338

Answer (score 0):

No. If you can't find the GTIN, you can try and contact the product's manufacturer to ask for it. Not all products will have a GTIN though. You cant just generate them yourself. You would have to pay for them.